# mocha + chai : nock returns "302 Found" for any http urls

Tags: mocha.js, chai, nock

I am trying to mock a remote service using chai-http and nock. If I provide the host url with "http://" I am getting "302 Found", full response is as follows:

> error:  StatusCodeError: 302 - "\r\n302
>   Found\r\n\r\n
>
> ## 302
>   Found
>
> \r\n
>
> ---
>
> nginx/1.13.4\r\n\r\n\r\n"

If I provide "https://", I am getting "Error:

> "Error: unable to get local issuer certificate"

My nock services are :

```
nock("http://dummy-service.test.com")
  .log(console.log)
  .get("/v1/app/" + id)
  .reply(200, itemResponse);

nock("http://dummy-service.test.com", {
  reqheaders: {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": authToken,
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "host": "dummy-service.test.com",
  },
})
  .log(console.log)
  .patch("/v1/app/" + id)
  .reply(200, patchSuccessResponse);
```

nock documentation shows http:// based requests, but I am not able to get them working.
Am I missing something? Any help would be much appreciated.